# App-Store-Review-Scraping: AppStoreScraper does not recognise app-id

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am very new in coding, just started this summer. I am trying to scrape reviews from App Store for 9 live-shopping-apps: https://www.apple.com/us/search/live-shopping?src=globalnav

I have created an xlsx-file with information about the apps and downloaded that as csv to the code, hoping that appstorescraper will identify apps through their id but it does not seem to work. Here is the code, originally retrieved from https://python.plainenglish.io/scraping-app-store-reviews-with-python-90e4117ccdfb:

````
import pandas as pd

# for scraping app info from App Store
from itunes_app_scraper.scraper import AppStoreScraper

# for scraping app reviews from App Store
from app_store_scraper import AppStore

# for pretty printing data structures
from pprint import pprint

# for keeping track of timing
import datetime as dt
from tzlocal import get_localzone

# for building in wait times
import random
import time

## Read in file containing app names and IDs
app_df = pd.read_csv('Data/app_.....ids.csv')
app_df.head()


app_name    iOS_app_name    iOS_app_id  url
4   Flip - Beauty and Shopping  flip-beauty-shopping    1470077137  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/flip-beauty-shop...
7   Spin Live   spin-live   1519146498  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spin-live/id1519...
1   Popshop - Live Shopping popshop-live-shopping   1009480270  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/popshop-live-sho...
5   Lalabox - Live Stream Shopping  lalabox-live-stream-shopping    1496718575  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lalabox-live-str...
6   Supergreat Beauty   supergreat-beauty   1360338670  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/supergreat-beaut...
8   HERO®   hero-live-shopping  1178589357  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hero-live-shoppi...
2   Whatnot: Buy, Sell, Gov Live    whatnot-buy-sell-go-live    1488269261  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatnot-buy-sell...
3   NTWRK - Live Video Shopping ntwrk-live-video-shopping   1425910407  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ntwrk-live-video...
0   LIT Live - Live Shopping    lit-live-live-shopping  1507315272  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lit-live-live-sh...


## Get list of app names and app IDs
app_names = list(app_df['iOS_app_name'])
app_ids = list(app_df['iOS_app_id'])```


## Set up App Store Scraper
scraper = AppStoreScraper()
app_store_list = list(scraper.get_multiple_app_details(app_ids))

## Pretty print the data for the first app
pprint(app_store_list[0])


https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1507315272&country=nl&entity=software
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itunes_app_scraper/scraper.py in get_app_details(self, app_id, country, lang, flatten)
    179                         result = json.loads(result)
--> 180                 except json.JSONDecodeError:
    181                         raise AppStoreException("Could not parse app store response")

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AppStoreException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-624146f96e92> in <module>
      1 ## Set up App Store Scraper
      2 scraper = AppStoreScraper()
----> 3 app_store_list = list(scraper.get_multiple_app_details(app_ids))
      4 
      5 app = result["results"][0]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itunes_app_scraper/scraper.py in get_multiple_app_details(self, app_ids, country, lang)
    205                 :param str lang: Dummy argument for compatibility. Unused.
    206 
--> 207                 :return generator:  A list (via a generator) of app details
    208         """
    209                 for app_id in app_ids:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itunes_app_scraper/scraper.py in get_app_details(self, app_id, country, lang, flatten)
    180                 except json.JSONDecodeError:
    181                         raise AppStoreException("Could not parse app store response")
--> 182 
    183                 try:
    184                         app = result["results"][0]

AppStoreException: No app found with ID 1507315272```

This is where I am stuck. It seems to be a simple problem but my experience is very limited. The url that App Store scraper use is not the same I used to retrieve app-ids from. Could this be the concern? Please help me to solve it. Thank you in advance!
````